# A probability question on infinite sets

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Suppose all members of a countably infinite set of people each pick an integer "at random" (I want to avoid uniform distributions for the obvious reasons). (I hope this setting makes enough sense for my question to have meaning; I would certainly appreciate constructive comments on this matter.)

Then what is the probability that at least one integer has been picked **an infinite number of times** ?

**EDIT**: my sentence "I want to avoid uniform distributions for the obvious reasons" was not understood by some, so I will formulate a more precise version as well which is less confusing (I hope). For this question, I will only assume *finite additivity* for probabilities (and not Kolgomorov's countable additivity), so that one can work with uniform distributions on countable infinite sets, which is what we do here. (I will call these generalized probabilities "f-probabilities.")

**QUESTION**: What is the f-probability that at least one integer has been picked **an infinite number of times** ?

Comment: What distribution do each of the persons pick according to?  Must they all pick from the same distribution?  Can they all pick from different distributions?  If they can pick from different distributions... and you were to have labeled the people $1,2,3,\dots$ what is stopping you from having person $i$ "*randomly pick*" from the distribution where they pick $i$ $100\%$ of the time?  If you complain that isn't "*random*" enough then they pick between $i$ and $i+1$ uniformly at random... You'll end up with every integer being picked exactly once (*or 0, 1 or 2 times if modified*)

Comment: @JMoravitz : I want to take a quantum take on this one, and let each person use a quantum random number generator to make his pick. (I am not sure how this relates to classical probability.)

Comment: I will emphasize again... *there is no uniform distribution on a countably infinite set*.  How are you avoiding this problem with your "quantum random number generators"... whatever those are.  Formally define the distribution they pick from or give some restriction to what distributions they pick from.

Comment: If we assume that each person select a number $i$ with same probability $p_i$ ($\sum p_i = 1$, e.g. $p_i=2^{-i}$), then  for $N$ persons, the number $i$  will as an average be selected $N\,p_i$ times. If $p_i>0$, the average number of times $i$ is selected tends to infinity. If we assume a different law for each person, then we cannot conclude. For example, if any person $i$ selects number $i$, no number will be selected an infinity number of times. (not an answer, to sure 100% of the reasonning).

Comment: Strengthening Damien's comment, consider the following model: A probability distribution $\mathbf{p}=(p_k)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is prescribed, and each person samples a random number according to the distribution $\mathbf{p}$ independently of all the other people. If there are countably many people, then we have: $$\mathbb{P}(\text{every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $p_k>0$ is picked infinitely many times})=1.$$ In other words, any integer which has ever slight chance to be picked will indeed be picked infinitely many times almost surely.

Comment: @AlexRavsky : can you write this out in an answer ? I think it would come in handy (even as simple as it is) for people first thinking on probabilities in the context of infinite sets. And I'll grant you the bounty :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the probabilities are finitely additive then the uniform distribution on a countably infinite set $X$ is trivial. Namely, suppose that each $x\in X$ has a probability $p(x)=p$ to be chosen. Since for each finite subset $F$ of $X$ we have $1\ge \sum_{x\in F} p(x)= \sum_{x\in F} p=p|F|$, we have $p=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In a first step, let us assume that each person selects a number $i$ with same probability $p_i$ ($\sum p_i = 1$).

A simple example:

$$p_i=2^{-i}$$

considering here only strictly positive integers.

Then  for $N$ persons, the number $i$  will as an average be selected $N\,p_i$ times, assuming selections
are done independently.

If $p_i>0$, the average number of times $i$ is selected tends to infinity, when $N$ tends to infinity.

With the above example, all numbers are selected an infinite number of times.

If we assume a different selection probability law for each person, then we cannot conclude. For example, if $i^{th}$ person selects number $i$, no number is selected an infinity number of times.